Unable to build custom action named because it uses a conditionally installed file
I followed this tutorial for making my .NET Core Windows service have an installer.
Before the tutorial, I published the files for the entry point project using the default folder publishing profile under the release build. I ran into the title error after trying to build the setup project (which you have to perform separately from the solution's build).
I am using .NET 8.0.

Adding 1 to the Condition boxes of the custom actions fixed the issue.
After adding the setup project, you go to the setup project > View > Custom Actions.
After adding the Install or Uninstall custom action, single click on the action, then either hit F4 or navigate to the Properties tab.
Set the Condition field to 1.
Build the setup project.
Not sure why I had to do this, but I hope this helps someone else.
